# FileSystemWatcher Event Bubbling

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I am using FileSystemWatcher to watch the incoming images (thru FTP) to the folder, where I am re-sizing the incoming images.

The problem is,  I am re-sizing the images by overwriting the original images; because of this FileSystemWatcher is continuously creating changed events. I want to suppress the FileSystemWatcher events while i am working on re-sizing and saving the re-sized images. but not while files being copied using FTP, which may happen simultaneously.
The incoming image count may reach up to 3000+ ...and I can not wait for more time to start processing.

Can anybody give me any solution to this.

Regards,

Amit Jog

Comment: Move the image to another folder and resize it there?

Comment: AFAIK, event bubbling is about events propagating up the class hierarchy.

Comment: why are you watching for CHANGED files?  Wouldnt CREATED files (new ones via FTP) be more appropriate, or can existing files get updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private thisFile as String = ""

' when resizing/etc:

thisFile = Name_of_file
```

Watcher event:

```
Private Sub FileChanged(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As  _
                System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)

    If e.FullPath.ToUpper = thisFile.ToUpper then exit sub
   ...

End Sub
```

You could also store all unprocessed images in a List(of String) and exempt them all as long as they are in the list (remove them when finished):

```
   If myList.Contains(e.FullPath.ToUpper) Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: This solution will bog down the application as these checks will happen each time an I/O is done on a file.

Comment: Thats true IF the watcher is set for all sorts of IO vs CREATE as when a file is received.  Even then, the only IO would be Reading the image and writing it back after resizing.

Comment: You are correct. The filter could be set to watch for created files only which will lower the event firing to an acceptable level.

Answer (score 0):

Set the FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter Property to NotifyFilters.CreationTime.